# Alterar o texto de um TextView que está dentro de um item do ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, android-layout

Fiz um `Adapter` que `extends` de `ArrayAdapter`. O meu layout contem apenas uma serie de `TextViews`, um em baixo do outro, bem simples.

Quero que um evento qualquer no sistema seja observado pelo meu `Adapter` e que um determinado item da lista seja alterado. Para isso estou usando o `EventBus`.

No construtor do meu `Adapter` eu uso `EventBus.getDefault().register(this);`

O Adapter tem um metodo `onEvent(MessageRunTask event){...}`

Eu criei um Job para rodar e testar, ele executa `EventBus.getDefault().post(new MessageRunTask(r));` quando termina, e usando o `Log.i` eu consigo confirmar que o medoto `onEvent` do `Adapter` está rodando com sucesso.

O que eu não sei fazer é:

Dentro do metodo `onEvent`, como eu faço para pegar o item X da lista e atualizar a propriedade `Text` do `TextView` Y que está dentro desse item X?

ATUALIZAÇÃO 1:

Segue o código do `Adapter` com as soluções tentadas:

```js
public class TarefaAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Tarefa> {

    private List<Tarefa> items;
    private int layoutResourceId;
    private Context context;
    private List<View> itensExibidos;

    public TarefaAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, List<Tarefa> items) {
        super(context, layoutResourceId, items);
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.context = context;
        this.items = items;

        this.itensExibidos = new ArrayList<View>();

        EventBus.getDefault().register(this);

    }

    public void onEvent(MessageRunTask event){



        if (!itensExibidos.isEmpty()) {

            //ESSE LOG APARECE
            Log.i("DEBUGEVENT", " teste");


            //TENTATIVA 1
            View v = itensExibidos.get(0);
            TarefasHolder ta = (TarefasHolder) v.getTag();
            ta.url.setText("Teste texto");

            //TENTATIVA 2
            TextView t = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.lblURL);
            t.setText("Teste texto");

            //TENTATIVA 3
            Tarefa teste = this.items.get(0);
            teste.url  = "Teste texto";

        }





    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


        View row = convertView;
        TarefasHolder holder = null;

        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

        holder = new TarefasHolder();
        holder.tarefa = items.get(position);
        holder.removePaymentButton = (Button)row.findViewById(R.id.btnExcluir);
        holder.removePaymentButton.setTag(holder.tarefa);

        holder.url = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.lblURL);
        holder.status = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.lblStatus);
        holder.lastexecute = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.lblLastExecute);
        holder.connectivity = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.lblConnectivity);
        holder.idle = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.lblIdle);
        holder.charging = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.lblCharging);
        holder.delay = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.lblDelay);


        row.setTag(holder);

        setupItem(holder);

        itensExibidos.add(row);

        return row;


    }

    private void setupItem(TarefasHolder holder) {
        holder.url.setText(holder.tarefa.url);
        holder.status.setText(trataStatus(holder.tarefa.status));
        holder.lastexecute.setText(trataData(holder.tarefa.lastexecute));
        holder.charging.setText(trataCharging(holder.tarefa.charging));
        holder.idle.setText(trataIdle(holder.tarefa.idle));
        holder.delay.setText(trataDelay(holder.tarefa.periodic));
        holder.connectivity.setText(trataNetworkType(holder.tarefa.networktype));
    }

    public static class TarefasHolder{

        Tarefa tarefa;
        TextView url;
        TextView status;
        TextView lastexecute;
        TextView connectivity;
        TextView delay;
        TextView charging;
        TextView idle;
        Button removePaymentButton;

    }


}
```

Essas são as tentativas que eu fiz.

Comment: Julgo que está a complicar algo que deve ser simples. Se esse *TextView* está no *Adapter* então o seu valor deveria de estar no array que é gerido por ele. Assim bastaria alterar esse valor no *array* para que essa alteração se reflectisse no item da *ListView*.

Comment: Então, ele está dentro, mas eu quero alterar o valor dele, cada linha dele é um Job rodando no sistema, quando o job termina eu tenho que ir no item especifico e altera-lo. Ou seja, o valor que foi usado para criar o `Adapter` mudou depois que o `Adapter` foi criado, eu preciso voltar nele e altera-lo.

Comment: Você tem é de alterar esse *"item especifico"* no array. Se assim não for, quando esse item sair da tela e voltar a ser apresentado, a alteração desaparece.

Comment: O adapter deve ter um objeto do tipo List, o que você tem que fazer é alterar os itens da lista.

Comment: Tentei alterar o `List`, não consegui fazer. Alterei a pergunta e adicionei todo o código que eu fiz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não é recomendado guardar a View criada na ListView, você não tem como garantir se essa view foi destruída.

Se é uma lista de texto, você cria uma lista de String e quando quiser alterar a lista basta mudar o texto da lista, exemplo abaixo:

(Dentro do adapter)

```
List<String> itens;

public void onEvent(MeuEvento me){
    //Sua lógica para saber qual item será alterado
    String s = itens.get(0);
    s = "mudei";
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```